# How to write java web services to upload image from android and use it in android

Tags: java

I see almost all webservice for android are written in PHP code. With Java I found an example of a rest service to upload image. I coded follow that code but when run test on my android device and Advanced RESTClient of chorme, I get error: HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error: Servlet.init () for servlet [Jersey REST Service] threw exception.. My URL: "http://srv.triaxvn.com:8080/logisticwsm/file/image-upload"

In android I use code:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private String uploadFile() {
File sourceFile = new File(filePath);
String fileName = sourceFile.getName();
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(FILE_UPLOAD_URL);
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
            // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
            entity.addPart("fileDescription", new StringBody(""));
            entity.addPart("fileName", new StringBody(fileName != null ? fileName : sourceFile.getName()));
            // Adding file data to http body
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(sourceFile, "application/octect-stream") ;
            entity.addPart("attachment", fileBody);
            //totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }
```

My Restful web service code:

```
@Path("/file")
public class UploadFile {

    private final String UPLOADED_FILE_PATH = "c:\\uploaded";

    @POST
    @Path("/image-upload")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) throws IOException
    {
        //Get API input data
        Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();

        //Get file name
        String fileName = uploadForm.get("fileName").get(0).getBodyAsString();

        //Get file data to save
        List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("attachment");

        for (InputPart inputPart : inputParts)
        {
            try
            {
                //Use this header for extra processing if required
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                MultivaluedMap<String, String> header = inputPart.getHeaders();

                // convert the uploaded file to inputstream
                InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);

                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
                // constructs upload file path
                fileName = UPLOADED_FILE_PATH + fileName;
                writeFile(bytes, fileName);
                System.out.println("Success !!!!!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return Response.status(200).entity("Uploaded file name : "+e.getMessage()).build();
            }
        }
        return Response.status(200)
                .entity("Uploaded file name : "+ fileName).build();
    }

    //Utility method
    private void writeFile(byte[] content, String filename) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File(filename);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fop.write(content);
        fop.flush();
        fop.close();
    }
```

I do not know the error caused from by android code or Server Restful code and how to fix it

Comment: I would start by really logging things. Enable yourself to observe what your code is doing!

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace.  Do you tested this service independently before using it with Android client.

Comment: I was deploy Restful service on Tomcat 9 details error: The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490). org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92). org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678).... java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ... om.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes